# Build ipa file in flutter using github actions

Tags: xcode, flutter, github-actions

I'm new to flutter, and I have a windows machine. I want to make ipa file for ios devices.

I want to achieve this by using GitHub actions.
and want to get the ipa file as a new release.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this workflow, it worked for me. Make sure first to do these steps:

1. You need to go to AppStoreConnect and obtain API_Issuer_ID, API_Key_Id, API_Private_Key under Apps/Users/Keys.

Also in Apple Developer you need to generate Apple Distribution profile and Certificate for signing, download them and do base64 encoding in order to import them in Github Secrets (under Settings of the github repository).

Example for base64:

```
base64 distribution_profile_path > encoded.txt
```

Then copy text from encoded.txt file and add it to Github Secrets with name: BUILD_PROVISION_PROFILE_BASE64.

Repeat the same for Certificate.

2. Note about other secrets:

P12_PASSWORD - thats a Apple Certificate password.

KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD - thats a normal password you can define and enter.
Make sure to add all Github secrets from the workflow file.
It should look like this:

[image: Github Secrets]

3. You also need to create ExportOptions.plist and put it under /ios folder inside the main project.
   Example for ExportOptions.plist: [example](https://jtmuller5-98869.medium.com/flutter-build-an-ipa-90520e813a96)

And here is the full workflow file. Pay attention to path to exported .ipa file. You will see path where .ipa is generated when step "Build the app" is executed. If this setup is not working for you, just add correct path you see to the step "Upload app to TestFlight" under APP_PATH variable:

```
jobs:
   iOS_Lane:
 name: iOS Lane
 runs-on: macos-latest
 env:
  PROJECT_DIRECTORY: name_of_your_project_directory
 defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: ./${{ env.PROJECT_DIRECTORY }}
 steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - uses: actions/setup-java@v2
    with:
      distribution: 'zulu'
      java-version: '11'
  - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
    with:
      flutter-version: '3.3.1'

  - name: Fetching Flutter dependencies
    run: flutter pub get

  - name: Linter
    run: flutter analyze

  - name: Executing tests
    run: flutter test --machine > test-results.json

  - name: Create Github Actions test result summary
    uses: dorny/test-reporter@v1
    with:
     name: 'Unit Test results'
     path: 'test-results.json'
     reporter: 'flutter-json'
     list-suites: 'all'
     list-tests: 'all'
     max-annotations: '10'
     fail-on-error: 'true'
     working-directory: ${{ env.PROJECT_DIRECTORY }}
     token: ${{ github.token }}
     
  - name: Generate build number
    id: buildnumber
    uses: einaregilsson/build-number@v3
    with:
     token: ${{secrets.github_token}}

  - name: Applying build number
    run: perl -i -pe 's/^(version:\s+\d+\.\d+\.)(\d+)(\+)(\d+)$/$1.($2).$3.(${{ steps.buildnumber.outputs.build_number }})/e' pubspec.yaml

  - name: Install the Apple certificate and provisioning profile
    env:
      BUILD_CERTIFICATE_BASE64: ${{ secrets.BUILD_CERTIFICATE_BASE64 }}
      P12_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.P12_PASSWORD }}
      BUILD_PROVISION_PROFILE_BASE64: ${{ secrets.BUILD_PROVISION_PROFILE_BASE64 }}
      KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD }}
    run: |
      # create variables
      CERTIFICATE_PATH=$RUNNER_TEMP/build_certificate.p12
      PP_PATH=$RUNNER_TEMP/build_pp.mobileprovision
      KEYCHAIN_PATH=$RUNNER_TEMP/app-signing.keychain-db
      # import certificate and provisioning profile from secrets
      echo -n "$BUILD_CERTIFICATE_BASE64" | base64 --decode --output $CERTIFICATE_PATH
      echo -n "$BUILD_PROVISION_PROFILE_BASE64" | base64 --decode --output $PP_PATH
      # create temporary keychain
      security create-keychain -p "$KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD" $KEYCHAIN_PATH
      security set-keychain-settings -lut 21600 $KEYCHAIN_PATH
      security unlock-keychain -p "$KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD" $KEYCHAIN_PATH
      # import certificate to keychain
      security import $CERTIFICATE_PATH -P "$P12_PASSWORD" -A -t cert -f pkcs12 -k $KEYCHAIN_PATH
      security list-keychain -d user -s $KEYCHAIN_PATH
      # apply provisioning profile
      mkdir -p ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
      cp $PP_PATH ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles

  - name: Build the app
    run: flutter build ipa --release --export-options-plist=ios/ExportOptions.plist

  - name: Clean up keychain and provisioning profile
    if: ${{ always() }}
    run: |
      security delete-keychain $RUNNER_TEMP/app-signing.keychain-db
      rm ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/build_pp.mobileprovision

  - name: Install private API key P8
    env:
      PRIVATE_API_KEY_BASE64: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_API_PRIVATE_KEY }}
      API_KEY: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_API_KEY_ID }}
    run: | 
      mkdir -p ~/private_keys
      echo -n "$PRIVATE_API_KEY_BASE64" | base64 --decode --output ~/private_keys/AuthKey_$API_KEY.p8

  - name: Upload app to TestFlight
    env:
      API_KEY: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_API_KEY_ID }}
      API_ISSUER: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_ISSUER_ID  }}
      APP_PATH: /Users/runner/work/name_of_your_project_directory/name_of_your_project_directory/name_of_your_project_directory/build/ios/ipa/*.ipa
    run: xcrun altool --upload-app --type ios -f $APP_PATH --apiKey $API_KEY --apiIssuer $API_ISSUER
```